# Swedish Tax Calculator

Tags: java, interview-questions, finance

I'm submitting this code in a couple of days as part of an an interview process.  The company knows that I don't have any formal experience with Java.  I'm hoping they are testing my ability to learn it on the fly.

This is my first non-trivial Java program and I'm looking for improvements and advice as if to whether I'm following "best practice" Java.

The comments below explain a bit about the program and example input/output is posted below as well.

The rounding was a bit weird, as it was always up to the next .05 cents to satisfy the requirements.

The code can be tested [here](http://ideone.com/ZEPZVl).

```
/*************************************************************************
 * RUN AT: http://ideone.com/ZEPZVl
 * REVIEWED AT: 
 *
 * ASSUMPTIONS: That the input is well-formed.  A group is terminated by 
 * an empty line of form "^\\s*$".  Headings are of the form
 * "^Input (\\d):".  Monetary values are of the form 
 * "(\\sat) ([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)".
 * 
 * MODIFYING: Strings that mark food, books and medical supplies can be set
 * in base_array.  String that mark imports can be set in import_array. 
 *
 * NOTE: This code was developed at ideone.com.  The final empty line
 * was not detected and I was required to put an END.  I assume the
 * the front end of the web-app was stripping trailing white space.
 * 
 *************************************************************************/

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Taxer taxer = new Taxer();
            taxer.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Taxer {

    private String[] import_array =  {"import"},
                     base_array = {"book", "chocolate", "pills"};
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final Pattern p_input = Pattern.compile("^Input (\\d):"),
                          p_money = Pattern.compile("(\\sat) ([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)"),
                          p_empty = Pattern.compile("^\\s*$");
    private final double TAX5 = .05,
                         TAX10 = .10;
    private double tax_group_sum = 0,
                   price_group_sum = 0,
                   price,
                   tax_import,
                   tax_base;
    private String line;

    public void run() {
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            analyzeLine();
        }
    }

    private void analyzeLine () {
        Matcher  m_input,
                 m_money,
                 m_empty;
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        m_input = p_input.matcher(line);
        m_money = p_money.matcher(line);
        m_empty = p_empty.matcher(line);
        price = 0;
        // heading
        if (m_input.find()) {
            System.out.println("Output " + m_input.group(1) + ":" );
        // line containing money amount
        } else if (m_money.find()) {
            line = m_money.replaceFirst(": ");
            price = Double.parseDouble(m_money.group(2));
            checkTaxed();
            checkImports();
            addValues();
            printLine();
        // empty line
        } else if(m_empty.find()) {
            printTotal();
            tax_group_sum = 0;
            price_group_sum = 0;
        // catch all echos input
        } else {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkImports () {
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;
        tax_import = 0;
        for (String s : import_array) {
            p = Pattern.compile(s);
            m = p.matcher(line);
            if(m.find()) {
                tax_import = roundSingleValue(price * TAX5);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkTaxed() {
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;
        tax_base = 0;
        for (String s : base_array) {
            p = Pattern.compile(s);
            m = p.matcher(line);
            if(m.find()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        tax_base = roundSingleValue(price * TAX10);
        return true;
    }

    private double roundSingleValue (double value) {
        double accuracy = 20;
        value = value * accuracy;
        value = Math.ceil(value);
        value = value / accuracy;
        return value;
    }
    private void addValues () {
        double tax_total = tax_base + tax_import;
        price = price + tax_total;
        tax_group_sum += tax_total;
        price_group_sum += price;
    }

    private void printTotal () {
        System.out.printf("Sales Taxes: %.2f%n", tax_group_sum);
        System.out.printf("Total: %.2f%n%n", price_group_sum);
    }

    private void printLine () {
        System.out.print(line);
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", price);
    }
}

/*
Input 1:
1 book at 12.49
1 music CD at 14.99
1 chocolate bar at 0.85

Input 2:
1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00
1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50

Input 3:
1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99
1 bottle of perfume at 18.99
1 packet of headache pills at 9.75
1 box of imported chocolates at 11.25

END
*/

/*
Output 1:
1 book: 12.49
1 music CD: 16.49
1 chocolate bar: 0.85
Sales Taxes: 1.50
Total: 29.83

Output 2:
1 imported box of chocolates: 10.50
1 imported bottle of perfume: 54.65
Sales Taxes: 7.65
Total: 65.15

Output 3:
1 imported bottle of perfume: 32.19
1 bottle of perfume: 20.89
1 packet of headache pills: 9.75
1 box of imported chocolates: 11.85
Sales Taxes: 6.70
Total: 74.68

END
*/
```

Comment: Also, consider a more functional approach - instead of methods that work on instance variables (reading or mutating), use parameters and returns.  This should help to limit side-effects, which can be a _huge_ cause of program errors.

Comment: they specifically asked for an oo approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few quick notes:

1. The catch block in the main method seems unnecessary. Throwing out exceptions has the same effect:

   ```
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
       final Taxer taxer = new Taxer();
       taxer.run();
   }
   ```
2. Try to minimize the scope of local variables. It's not necessary to declare them at the beginning of the method, declare them where they are first used. (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*)
3. Don't use floating point variables where you may need exact results:

   - *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*
   - [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)
4. Variable name prefixes are unnecessary and uncommon in the Java world. See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*